# How to get the field of an Entity that is passed as a generic argument to a function in Java?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, generic-programming

I have a generic method that receives any of the entity class. All my entities have a createDate field of type LocalDate. I want to access and get the field inside the generic method. The method would be something like this

```
public static < T > List<Resource> printArray( List<T> entity) {
    for( T e : entity ) {
        LocalDate d = e.getCreateDate(); //Wrong
    }
```

I don't want to check the instance of the generic argument and type cast it as there are lot of entities and I want the code to be minimal (Hence the generic function).
How can I do this?

Comment: Do your entities all have a common parent class? Or is there just one type?

Comment: No common parent class. All entities have a common field. @dave

Comment: You could create a common parent class then (say `BaseClass`), that holds this date field and its accessors. Then use `<T extends BaseClass>`. Once you've done this you should be able to access `e.getCreateDate()`.

Comment: No other way? I don't want to change the existing entities in the project. @dave

Comment: No. If you don't want to cast (and you shouldn't) then you need to modify your classes to support this cleanly and clearly. You can work around it with reflection, but this further highlights there's something missing from your design.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an interface with abstract method `getCreateDate()`

```
interface IDate {
    LocalDate getCreateDate();
}
```

And assuming all your entities have implemented this interface your method will look like:

```
public static <T extends IDate> List<Resource> printArray(List<T> entity) {
    for(T e : entity ) {
        LocalDate d = e.getCreateDate();
    }
}
```

Otherwise you cannot guarantee that entities you passed into this method have method `getCreateDate()`

There is reflection solution suggested by [@VHS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54847435/5108737)

Comment: Is there any other way? Because I don't want to change the entities as they already exist in the project. For my piece of code I don't want to change the existing entities. @Ruslan

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to call a method with a given name on the generic type.

```
    for( T e : entity ) {
        try {
            Method method = e.getClass().getMethod("getCreateDate");
            method.invoke(e);
        }
        catch(Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }                       
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the entity types do not have a common supertype to declare the `getCreateDate` method and you can’t change the type hierarchy, you have to use delegation:

```
public static <T> List<Resource> printArray(
    List<? extends T> entities, Function<? super T, ? extends LocalDate> accessor) {

    for(T e: entities ) {
        LocalDate d = accessor.apply(e);
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

This method can be invoked like

```
printArray(listOfEntities, EntityType::getCreateDate);
```

where `EntityType` refers to the particular element type of the list.